# Cancellable remote processes and capturing output

Tags: c#, powershell, process, cancellation

I'm trying to use PowerShell via its C# API to do the following:

1. start remote processes
2. terminate them
3. capture standard and error output of remote processes (not after the process terminates, but as that output is being produced).
4. capture the exit code of remote processes.

I'm starting remote processes with the following PowerShell script:

```
$ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps
$ps.StartInfo.Filename = "c:\Echo.exe"
$ps.StartInfo.Arguments = ""
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ps.start()
$ps.WaitForExit()
$ps.ExitCode
```

The C# part of my prototype looks like the following:

```
// Note: in this example the process is started locally
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(/*_remotePcConnectionInfo*/))
{
    runspace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    // Scripts.RunExecutable is that script above
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(Scripts.RunExecutable);

    pipeline.InvokeAsync();

    var process = (Process)pipeline.Output.Read().BaseObject;

    bool started = (bool)pipeline.Output.Read().BaseObject;

    // Not showing the dummy event handlers - they simply do a Console.WriteLine now.
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // Not showing the dummy event handlers - they simply do a Console.WriteLine now.
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    int processExitCode = (int) pipeline.Output.Read().BaseObject;
}
```

This does capture the output of processes run locally, but **will this work for remote processes as well?** (Another, less important question is: how can this work for remote processes? Is .Net Remoting involved in some way and am I getting a proxy for Process?) **If not, what's the way to do that? Do mind that I need the output as it's being produced, not after the process is terminated**.

This does not capture process termination. I've tried doing termination by capturing process Id first and then running "Stop Process " PowerShell script from a different runspace. That failed, because "the pipeline is already running" and pipelines cannot run in parallel... Then I've tried invoking process.Kill() from C#, **that worked for my local process, but SO reports it won't work for remote processes...** Then I've tried tuning my PowerShell script so it included a global variable and a waiting loop, but I never figured out how to set that variable after the pipeline is started. The added loop looked like this:

```
while ($ps.HasExited -eq $false -and $global:cancelled -eq $false)
{
    Start-Sleep -seconds 1
}

if ($global:cancelled -eq $true)
{
    $ps.Kill()
}
```

So, that failed, too. **Any advice on process termination for my scenario?**

**Is PowerShell even a good fit for this?** (we're strongly against openSSH we've tried using before because of its issues with forking).

**UPDATE:** What I've ended up doing was calling (via C# starting a process -- "powershell" + "-Command ...") into powershell.exe that was told to execute a script (invoke-command) on a remote computer. Powershell captures output produced on remote PC by default, so I could easily get this of the Process instance. When I wanted to cancel, I killed the local process. The return code of a remote command was trickier. I will post the command, script and C#-snippet in a while.

Comment: That first snippet of powershell won't start a remote process. It starts a process locally. Are you using jobs or remoting to execute it?

Comment: @mikez I'm using remoting by creating a remote runspace (it's not shown explicitly though, I'm only saying that in comments). So it was my understanding, that this snippet does run on a remote machine.

Comment: Check out the [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell) library, which greatly simplifies handling process io streams. With MedallionShell, you can also easily and safely terminate any process via the Kill() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell Jobs can be executed remotely and will capture their output and return it to the originating machine. With this you wouldn't have to create a remote runspace in C#, just a local one.

The powershell script to do this would look like this:

```
$job = invoke-command -computername remotecomputer -scriptblock { start-process "C:\Echo.exe" -wait } -asjob
while ( $job.State -eq "Running" ) {
  wait-job -job $job -timeout 1
  receive-job -job $job -keep # print the current output but keep all output for later.
}

receive-job -job $job
```

You would probably just need to tweak the scriptblock parameter to `invoke-command` to get the exit code if wanted that in the output as well.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. I'm planning on hundreds of processes being executed on hundreds of PCs at any given time. Is managing them all from local runspace (as jobs) possible in PowerShell? It seems to be complaining even if I create a second pipeline and try using it, while the first one I've created is not closed. (I'm new to PowerShell and seem to be missing some core concept here.)

Comment: I expect that it is possible. The computername parameter actually accepts an array of names so you could do it like this: `invoke-command -computername $computernames -scriptblock { start-process "C:\Echo.exe" -wait } -asjob`

Comment: I see. It won't be a single command running of all of the PCs, the commands will be different and unrelated to one another.

Comment: Failed to get any output from remote machine. That script printed nothing (even in PS console) except for the info on the job (name, status, etc). I'm thinking of moving to using winrs command line started from .Net application as a process. The output will be redirected automatically, and termination of that process will mean command cancellation.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your help on this! I've updated the question with the idea I've taken in the end. I will post the details tomorrow, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on the Process object it will only allow you to start & stop local processes.  Therefore if you want to start & stop remote processes then you need to use either PowerShell remoting or a tool like psexec.  I see your C# comments indicate you would set up a remote runspace.  That works great if you have PowerShell v2 on each remote computer, have remoting enabled, preferably are on a domain and have the appropriate admin credentials. IIRC the C# process setting up the remote runspace must run as admin and the credentials it uses must have admin rights on the remote computer (unless you've set up special remoting endpoints on each of the remote computers).

If you do have PowerShell v2 or v3 on each remote computer and can enable remoting (just run Enable-PSRemoting -force) then you should easily be able to do what you want.  However, there is no need to drop down to use the .NET Process object.  Just use PowerShell cmdlets. Put something like this in a script, add that to the pipeline your create and invoke that.

```
$p = Start-Process Echo.exe -Arg "output from echo.exe" -PassThru
$p | Wait-Process -Timeout 3 # 3 seconds
if (!$?) { # Success code $? returns $false if Wait-Process times out
    $p | Stop-Process
}
```

For async support, try it this way:

```
$script = {
    $pid
    ipconfig.exe /all
    $LastExitCode
}
$job = Invoke-Command localhost $script -AsJob
do {
    Receive-Job $job
}
while (!(Wait-Job $job -Timeout 1))
Receive-Job $job    
Remove-Job $job
```

With the returned $pid, you can use that along with WMI to find all the child process to kill them if necessary like so:

```
$childPids = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessID=$PID" |Select-Object -Property ProcessID)
```

Comment: Keith, thank you for your reply. I will try out the cmdlets in the next 24 hours. Any ideas on asynchronously (that is: without waiting for process to finish) capturing the output of process from C# code? As for the cancellation, I didn't mean the timeout scenario, although that might be useful, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This indeed starts a process, but I was unable to asynchronously stop it or get its standard output - drowned in PowerShell .Net API.

Comment: Keith, thanks for assistance! I've updated the question with the idea I've taken in the end. I will post the details tomorrow, if you're interested.